# ProxyPass for specific vhost with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

I have a web server that it set up to dynamically server different document roots for different domains

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        # Stage sites :: www.[document root].server.company.com => /home/www/[document root]
        RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST}          ^www\.[^.]+\.server\.company\.com$
        RewriteRule   ^(.+)                 %{HTTP_HOST}$1          [C]
        RewriteRule   ^www\.([^.]+)\.server\.company\.com(.*) /home/www/$1/$2  [L]
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

This makes it so that `www.foo.server.company.com` will serve the document root of `server.company.com:/home/www/foo/`

For one of these sites, I need to add a `ProxyPass`, but I only want it to be applied to that one site.  I tried something like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory /home/www/foo>
        UseCanonicalName Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPass /services http://www-test.foo.com/services
        ProxyPassReverse /services http://www-test.foo.com/services
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But then I get these errors

> ProxyPreserveHost not allowed here
>
> ProxyPass|ProxyPassMatch can not have a path when defined in a location.

How can I set up a `ProxyPass` for a single virtual host?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just move the `ProxyPass` out of the `<Directory>` block - if it's in that context, it's expected that it applies to that exact context (instead of the `/services` you want it to apply for).

Actually, you're not doing anything with that block at all, it looks like?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    UseCanonicalName Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass /services http://www-test.foo.com/services
    ProxyPassReverse /services http://www-test.foo.com/services
    # and if you do need to serve from /home/www/foo...
    DocumentRoot /home/www/foo
    <Directory /home/www/foo>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**edit:** Missed that it's not actually virtual hosts - your example where it's just a directory in a virtual host block made me think they were separate.

In that case...

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
# If it's not already:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.foo
RewriteRule ^/services(.*) http://www-test.foo.com/services$1 [P,L]
ProxyPassReverse /services http://www-test.foo.com/services
```

Comment: I'd add that the reason that ProxyPass doesn't work in a `<Directory>` context is that Directory means a path in the filesystem. But the whole point of proxying is to replace that path with a connection to the backend server. So, in essence the ProxyMatch will replace the Directory.

Comment: Wouldn't this break `www.bar.server.company.com` and `www.biz.server.company.com` buy using a different doc root?

Comment: @SteveRobbins No, each virtual host has its own document root (or inherits from the server configuration if it doesn't have one configured).

Comment: But it's a pseudo document root by way of `mod_rewrite`

Comment: @SteveRobbins Ahh.  See edit.

Answer (score 1):

**Use a New VirtualHost**

If you add a new `VirtualHost` above your current one and specify the domain in `ServerName`, you can then proxy that specific domain.

You may need to add a `NameVirtualHost` if you are on Apache prior to version 2.3.11.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.targetdomain.com
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass /services http://www-test.foo.com/services
        ProxyPassReverse /services http://www-test.foo.com/services

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        # Stage sites :: www.[document root].server.company.com => /home/www/[document root]
        RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST}          ^www\.[^.]+\.server\.company\.com$
        RewriteRule   ^(.+)                 %{HTTP_HOST}$1          [C]
        RewriteRule   ^www\.([^.]+)\.server\.company\.com(.*) /home/www/$1/$2  [L]
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

I recommend setting `ProxyRequests Off` at the server level.

When Apache tries to match domain names it does so on a first match basis.  The first match (VirtualHost, ServerName, or ServerAlias) in the configuration file will be the one used to route the traffic. There is no special treatment for wildcards, so any specific server name declarations need to appear before your wildcard virtual host.

`ProxyPreserveHost` is permitted only in the Server and VirtualHost context.  So if you must use that directive, you will need to place it in a new VirtualHost.